# Kernal Panics, High Sierra : Late 2013 MacBook Pro Retina 15"

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I've fully wiped my SSD and installed a fresh copy of high sierra using internet recovery. I've made sure to not install all the apps I usually use. I still get a Kernal Panic every now and then and it's worrying.

I've attached a pastebin link with the Problem Report that generated.
Kernal Panics Macbook Pro retina - [link]pastebin.com/f2UhbLMH)

Comment: No link....  Also, have you tried booting into Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting)?

Comment: [link]https://pastebin.com/f2UhbLMH)

Answer (score 1):

Usually kernel issues are related to software but they can also be caused by bad hard drives. I would boot the Mac into recovery mode (turn mac on, hold down "command" + R until you see the Apple Logo. And then go to Disk Utility and run a First Aid on your Macintosh HD hard drive (do all hard drives anyway just to make sure). If it passes then try reinstalling macOS (OS X). If it fails I'd replace it and do a backup of it ASAP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've already used command R to reinstall a fresh copy of MacOS High Sierra on a fully wiped drive. As this is a newer MacBook Pro the SSD is not as easily changed out. I've been able to run the MacBook for a while now without a kernel panic so it seems to be a software issue. Specifically it looks like it had to do with the initial upgrade to high sierra a few months ago which must've cause an error in converting from HFS to APFS.

Comment: I would call Apple Support or make a reservation to the Apple Store\Best Buy near you for an inspection.